Difference in responses from arkworks and Substrate rust crates for Field elements in bn254 curves?
I am migrating a code from arkworks(ark_bn254 0.3.0) to substrate_bn(0.6.0) and I am trying to get a Vec<u8> from an Fr elements from both to check if I am getting the same response . Here is the Code I am using .
fn main() {
    let arkworks_fr = get_fr_mask();
    let substrate_fr = get_fr_mask_substrate();

    println!("{:?}",arkworks_fr);
    println!("{:?}",substrate_fr);

    let u8_arksworks = get_u8arr_from_fr(arkworks_fr);
    // [31, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255]
    let u8_substrate = get_u8arr_from_fr_sub(substrate_fr);

    println!("{:?}",u8_arksworks);
    println!("{:?}",u8_substrate);

    let in_u256 = arith::U256::from_slice(u8_arksworks.as_slice()).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}",in_u256);
    
}

the function get_fr_mask just gets this field element
pub fn get_fr_mask/get_fr_mask_substrate() -> Fp256<FrParameters>/Fr {
    Fr::from_str("14474011154664524427946373126085988481658748083205070504932198000989141204991")
        .unwrap()
}


Here are the functions to convert to Vec<u8>
//arkworks
pub fn get_u8arr_from_fr(fr: Fp256<FrParameters>) -> Vec<u8> {
    get_bigint_from_fr(fr).to_bytes_be().1
}

pub fn get_bigint_from_fr(fr: Fp256<FrParameters>) -> BigInt {
    let mut st = fr.to_string();
    println!("Fr to string {:?}",st.clone());
    let temp = &st[8..8 + 64];
    println!("string to eight bytes removed {:?}",temp.clone());
    BigInt::parse_bytes(temp.as_bytes(), 16).unwrap()
}
//substrate_bn
pub fn get_u8arr_from_fr_sub(fr: Fr) -> Vec<u8> {
    // println!("Fr to string substrate {:?}", fr.to_string());
    let mut bytes = [0u8; 32];
    fr.to_big_endian(&mut bytes).unwrap();
    bytes.to_vec()
}

Ideally they should have been the same but substrate_bn gives a wildly different number . Moreover when I try to get a U256 elements from the vec<u8> of arkworks I get a different U256 element as stored in the Fr of substrate_bn.
Here are the console logs
Fp256(BigInteger256([2539780544120761787, 4665084978088598710, 4212232780545764683, 2929937447749533076]))
Fr(Fr(U256([86055628672907311710087816179976777147, 54047806250613388313262288085867015499])))
Fr to string "Fp256 \"(1FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)\""
string to eight bytes removed "1FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF"
[31, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255]
[40, 169, 58, 149, 211, 57, 189, 148, 58, 116, 219, 101, 131, 175, 173, 75, 64, 189, 182, 18, 37, 251, 92, 182, 35, 63, 28, 242, 211, 196, 45, 187]
U256([340282366920938463463374607431768211455, 42535295865117307932921825928971026431])

